# Why my proxy is still having some connections blocked

Tags: firewalls, ssh, proxy

I am behind a firewall in France. I connect to  proxy A, in Ireland with Dante via SSH port 22 and make a tunnel forwarding port 1080. The proxy works as expected but still having a port range blocked.

I suspect the firewall does deep packet inspection.

But where is the blocking happening? At what layer?

Do you recommend some modification to the the technique I am using to be able to bypass it?

Comment: Too little details about what you're doing, it's not possible to evaluate exactly what hosts, connections and layers you use at all. If you want to verify your hypothesis about deep packet inspection, you can try key-based authentication rather than password-based. As intermediate hosts do not access your secret key, they're not able to decrypt your data even by sniffing your session right from the very beginning. So if you're still blocked, then DPI is not the case.